# Sort Android apps alphabetically?

Tags: android, sorting, arraylist

I have the following code:

```
packageManager = getPackageManager();
    List<PackageInfo> packageList = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
    List<PackageInfo> installedapps = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();

    for(PackageInfo apps: packageList){
        if(!isSystemPackage(apps)){
            installedapps.add(apps);
        }
    }


   Collections.sort(installedapps, new Comparator<PackageInfo>(){
        public int compare(PackageInfo o1, PackageInfo o2) {
            return o1.packageName.compareTo(o2.packageName);
        }
    });



    apkList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    apkList.setAdapter(new AppInfoAdapter(this, installedapps, packageManager));
```

installedapps is a list of all the apps on the device minus the system apps. The only thing I want to do is sort them alphabetically, can't quite figure out how.

Comment: Just sort your list before passing it to your adapter. http://blog.vogella.com/2009/08/04/collections-sort-java/

Comment: I'm just confused by what I'm comparing, I used:
    Collections.sort(installedapps, new Compater<PackageInfo> etc.
What I'm confused about is what I should be comparing for the two PackageInfo objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to sort a list of `PackageInfo` objects alphabetically by name. I would start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property). What you want to do is create a custom Comparator for the ArrayList you called `installedapps` and then sort is using `Collections.sort(..)`. The property of `PackageInfo` you should use for sorting is `p.packageName` which is the fully qualified name of the Application (you can use regular expressions to isolate the last piece of the package name). An example of isolating cosmetic properties of apps you can find [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-installed-applications-with-name-package-name-version-and-icon).

Comment: Added the Collections.sort() as suggested, that was the idea I had earlier, and now I'm moreso convinced I'm on the right track, but this isn't working. Are there any glaring mistakes, or is this right and I should maybe look elsewhere for a mistake?

Comment: Got it! I was looking to compare applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString() instead of .packageName

Comment: Note that if you want to compare PackageInfo (as mentioned in the original question), not ApplicationInfo, then my answer here might be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47198817/997940

Answer (score 0):

Android provides an ApplicationInfo.DisplayNameComparator which can be used for sorting of

```
List<ApplicationInfo>
```

Check out: [Alphabatize list of installed apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174360/alphabatize-list-of-installed-apps)