# How to sort out a List<PackageInfo> in android..?

Tags: java, android

```
List<PackageInfo> pkginfoList = getPackageManager()
                .getInstalledPackages(0);
```

How to Sort the `PackageInfo`, i did `ApplicationInfo` thats working fine

```
Collections.sort(installedList, new ApplicationInfo.DisplayNameComparator(packageManager));
```

but i want implement `PackageInfo` also..

i'm not sure how to do.. Please any one help me...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method takes two parameters:

1. The list you want to sort
2. And a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) object used to compare elements which type is the type of elements in your list.

In your case you want to implement a `Comparator<PackageInfo>`. An example supposing a `PackagInfo` has a `getName()` method:

```
new Comparator<PackagInfo>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(PackagInfo arg0, PackagInfo arg1) {
      return arg0.getName().compareTo(arg1.getName());
    }
 };
```

Another solution is to get one from somewhere but I don't know Android well. Looking at the piece of code you provided, maybe you have a PackageInfo.xxxx static field which type is `Comparator<PackageInfo>` ?

Answer (score 2):

Since Manuel Selva's answer didn't really work for me, here's what I did to improve it - assuming you want to sort the packages according to their app's name:

```
Collections.sort(packages, new Comparator<PackageInfo>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(PackageInfo arg0, PackageInfo arg1) {
        CharSequence name0 = arg0.applicationInfo.loadLabel(Context.getPackageManager());
        CharSequence name1 = arg1.applicationInfo.loadLabel(Context.getPackageManager());
        if (name0 == null && name1 == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (name0 == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (name1 == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        return name0.toString().compareTo(name1.toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: The comparator is using `ResolveInfo` instead of `PackageInfo`

Comment: @Ampersanda sorry but I couldn't understand, where do you see ResolveInfo here?

Comment: I use your code before, but the `Collections.sort()` second parameter is `Comparator< ResolveInfo >` now

Comment: @Ampersanda what type did you use for the first parameter? see the official docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html (look for the second sort() function)

Comment: if statements are unnecessary

Comment: @YasiruNayanajith I don't remember what made me add them, but perhaps in some cases it can be null?

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is already answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924409/sort-android-apps-alphabetically) post.

Did you try looking for existing posts with the solution before creating a new question ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. ok buddy.. i searched but never get the answer thats way i posted my queries. i will look at on as your suggestion